# How can I find ∠ADC?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles, angle

Here is the picture:

[image]

v=16 and w=25 and d is the angle of reference. I have to find ∠ADC.

Here is what I have done:

$\frac {sin(∠adc)}{25}$=$\frac {sin(30)} {16}$

sin(∠adc)=$\frac {25sin(30)} {16}$

∠adc=arcsin($\frac {25sin(30)} {16}$)

∠adc = 51.4

which means that ∠ADC=51.4. It is pretty obvious that it is incorrect because of the look of the angle. What did I do wrong and how do I find the right answer?

Comment: what is d?........

Comment: @Aqua It is the angle. I fixed it to make it more obvious

Comment: Besides, why don't you plot the triangle $ADC$ only? The point $B$ and the length $u$ play obviously no role here.

Comment: @user This picture is for two different questions. The other one I already solved

Comment: It is better to avoid superfluous details while asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

If $0\leq a\leq 1$ the equation:  $$\sin x = a$$ has two solutions in $[0,\pi]$, namely $x_1 = \arcsin a$ and $x_2 = \pi -x_1$.

Comment: For $a=1$ I would count the two solutions for one. :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand with this Wikipedia explanation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#The_ambiguous_case_of_triangle_solution